GitBash Terminal Crashes When Adding Files, Including .gitignore, to Staging Area
I'm working on a Node.js project and encountering an issue while pushing to my GitHub repository. I've added the node_modules folder to the .gitignore file to exclude it from Git, but when I use the git add . command, Git still reads the node_modules folder, causing the terminal to continuously process files until I manually stop it with ctrl+c or by killing the terminal.
Status of 'node_module' folder before adding it to '.gitignore' file :

$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        app.js
        database.js
        node_modules/
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        public/
        views/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


Status of 'node_module' folder after adding it to '.gitignore' file :

$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        app.js
        database.js
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        public/
        views/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

When I try to add the files to staging area from working area :

$ git add .
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.bin/ejs', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.bin/ejs.ps1', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.bin/jake', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.bin/jake.ps1', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.bin/mime', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.bin/mime.ps1', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/.package-lock.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@kurkle/color/LICENSE.md', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it........it goes on 

The warning messages indicate that Git is still processing files
in the 'node_modules' directory, even though it's listed in '.gitignore'.
I don't know how the files inside the 'node_modules' are read. 
Thankyou for any advice

